# Analogue of IBM COS ListObjectsV2 on Azure Blob Storage

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

Good day. I've the following code snippet for interacting with IBM Cloud Storage in Java:

```
ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request()
    .withBucketName(bucket)
    .withPrefix(prefix)
    .withMaxKey(keyCount)
    .withContinuationToken(token)
    .withSdkClientExecutionTimeut(timeout);
ListObjectsV2Result result = cosConfig.getClient().listObjectsV2(request);
result.getObjectSummaries()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().endsWith(extension))
    .forEach(e -> map.put(
        e.getKey().substring(e.getKey().lastIndexOf("/") + 1),
        e.getETag()
    ));
if (result.isTruncated()) {
    token = result.getNextContinuationToken();
}
```

But can't find exact alternative on Azure Blob. Do I understand correctly that it's easier to get a container and then find the necessary ones in the list of blobs?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I understand correctly that it's easier to get a container and then find the necessary ones in the list of blobs?

Yes, that's correct. This is the exact hierarchy of Azure Blob Storage.

**Azure Blob Storage** is optimized for storing massive amounts of unstructured data. Unstructured data is data that does not adhere to a particular data model or definition, such as text or binary data. Blob storage offers three types of resources:

- **The storage account**
- **A container in the storage account**
- **A blob in the container**

[image]

**Java v12 SDK** allows you to interact with `Containers` and `Blobs`. This SDK provides classes to interact with these resources:

- **BlobServiceClient:** The `BlobServiceClient` class allows you to manipulate Azure Storage resources and blob containers. The storage account provides the top-level namespace for the Blob service.
- **BlobServiceClientBuilder:** The `BlobServiceClientBuilder` class provides a fluent builder API to help aid the configuration and instantiation of `BlobServiceClient` objects.
- **BlobContainerClient:** The `BlobContainerClient` class allows you to manipulate Azure Storage containers and their blobs.
- **BlobClient:** The `BlobClient` class allows you to manipulate Azure Storage blobs.
- **BlobItem:** The `BlobItem` class represents individual blobs returned from a call to `listBlobs`.

For code example to work with these classes, please visit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell%2Cenvironment-variable-windows#code-examples).